# Inheritance controller in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a lot of controllers in controller's folder like this :

```
app
controller (folder)
  -> admin (folder)
     -> C_admin_eir
     -> C_admin_eir_first_revisi
```

How can I make the class `C_admin_eir_first_revisi` is a inheritance from `C_admin_eir`

I create like this :
**C_admin_eir**

```
<?php

 namespace App\controllers;

 if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class C_admin_eir extends Admin_Controller {

      public $data = array(
        'halaman' => 'home',
        'main_view' => 'admin/v_home'
     );
}
```

**C_admin_eir_first_revisi**

```
  namespace App\controllers;

  use App\controllers\C_admin_eir;

  if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
     exit('No direct script access allowed');
  class C_admin_eir_first_revisi extends C_admin_eir {
     public $data = array(
         'halaman' => 'First Revisi',
         'main_view' => 'admin/v_home_revisi'
  );

   /*  SOME OVERRIDE FUNCTION*/

}
```

Error : Fatal error: Class 'App\controllers\C_admin_eir'

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry in codeigniter you are not allowed to do that, extend the base controller in side the application/core/Controller.php

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by moving your controllers to the global namespace. Here is an example:

Parent_ctrl.php

```
class Parent_ctrl extends CI_Controller
{
    public function parent_method()
    {
        echo 'I am parent_method';
    }
}
```

Child_ctrl.php

```
require APPPATH.'controllers/Parent_ctrl.php';

class Child_ctrl extends Parent_ctrl
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->parent_method();
    }
}
```